# How to fix "extra space" in Login Card using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am making a simple login with bootstrap and I am having a problem dealing with this, here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters" style="padding-top:150px;">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="card shadow-lg o-hidden border-0 my-5 mx-auto">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 p-0">
                                <div class="p-5">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <h4 class="text-dark mb-4">Login</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <form class="user">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" type="email" id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username" name="email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" type="password" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary d-block btn-user w-100" type="submit">Login</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the result:
[image: Imgur Photo]

Can somebody help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used 'col-lg-6'. On large screen it contains only half width of the row. If you remove this class There won't be any extra space. You can read more about [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)